# How to bind the value in client side using ajax and mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery

I need to bind the value in html list box. But ajax and return the value in client side. but it has the proper rerun value. I think Its return format is wrong. How to change this? My code is given below

```
  public ActionResult value(bool sta1, bool sta2)
        {
                // my code
            return Json(Selectedstudents.ToList(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

ajax:

```
    $.ajax({
       //my code
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) { // not trigger here
          // my code
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax ( {
       url : "/ControllerName/Value"
       type:  'Get'
       data : { val1 : value1, val2:value2 }
       datatype: 'json'
       success : function(data) {
                           $("#listboxid").html(data);
                               do something...
        }
});
```

and in controller

```
public JsonResult value(bool val1, bool val2)
        {
                // my code
            result.Data = Selectedstudents.ToList();
            result.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
            return result;

        }
```

Comment: i know this code. problem is return json format in my controller?

Comment: everything is fine in controller...try to use Net tab in and see if there is any request or not..